# Is it allowed to post a link when the solution provided works?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I asked a question that received an answer that worked. Am I allowed to post a link to my client's page, showing how the answer worked, in a comment, to the answer I upvoted, to help others who may be looking for an example?

I used the search function to find an answer to this question, but came up empty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*If you want to post a link to your answer in another question*, it might be better to vote for that question to be closed as a duplicate if it's the same question.

*If your link helps clarify an answer by adding to or explaining the answer*, aka supporting material, then sure comment with the link. E.g. a tutorial that's similar but explains it in a different way. Another example of this might be adding more information to the answer by linking to a related wikipedia article, or a related question.

*If the link leads to a codepen style site or a github repo that acts as an example of using the answer*, that's okay too, though rare. E.g. *"Ah yes! This is what the XYZ library does at [https://github.com/....."](https://github.com/.....%22)*

*If the link just leads to a place that used the answer though*, then **no**, that doesn't help the answer, or enhance/improve it. If it worked for you, you don't need to link to your site where you used it, **up vote instead**.

Linking to your site in this way would be self-promotion and many would consider it spam. If you linked to an article on your site on the subject that expanded on the answer, that's different though.

Comment: I may not have explained clearly. What I mean is that I was thinking of adding a comment to the answer that worked showing that it worked and what the result looks like on the front side. It has to do with some dynamic linking code for a WordPress site.

Comment: Unless it's a code-sharing specific site such as Codepen it may be seen as spamy or promotional. If an answer works I think it's more beneficial to just upvote it.

Comment: @NoraMcDougall-Collins can you edit/update your question to make that clear?

Comment: I updated my question. Do you find that my changes communicate better?